# TCPF with unknowned simbols

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I've this problem with my code.

I'm trying to get the spanish special chars with accents and the "ñ" and "€".

That's my code:

```
include_once(PLUGINS_PATH . "tcpdf/tcpdf.php");
$pdf = new TCPDF("L", PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, false, 'ISO-8859-1', false);

// Deshabilitando la cabecera
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);

// Deshabilitando el pie de página
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

// Márgenes
$pdf->SetMargins(5, 5, 5);

// Saltos de página automáticos.
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// Establecer el ratio para las imagenes que se puedan utilizar
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// Establecer la fuente
$pdf->SetFont('times',  10);

// Añadir pána
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, 2, 2, $html, 0);

//Cerramos y damos salida al fichero PDF
return $pdf->Output($pdf_path_name, 'F');
```

the $html variable contains all the information and when I display with a simple echo $html it well encoded.

I give you one pic with my PDF.

http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/9451/kw97.png

**Solved the problem displaying european simbols.
But why I'm getting those "??????" simbols?
I give you another pic
http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/6342/42th.png**

PD: I've been looking for one solution for 3 days and no solution i've found.

Answer (score 0):

You have specified `ISO-8859-1` which is more commonly known as Latin-1.  Latin-1 does include those characters.  But you should specify your coalition/encoding to be `UTF-8` which will likely cover all of the special characters you need.

After reading some of the [documentation](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a134232ae3ad1ec186ed45046f94b7755), it doesn't appear that they use the ISO standards to identify the different types of encoding, but it isn't clear.

```
$pdf = new TCPDF("L", PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

Comment: Solved the problem displaying european simbols. But why I'm getting those "??????" simbols? I give you another pic http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/6342/42th.png

Comment: @Subiendo What symbols are they supposed to be?

Comment: None, that symbol are supposed not to be there, that field only contains a phonenumber with 6 digits. that field is supposed to contain the string "774050"

Comment: I wish I could tell you, I'm not sure.  Make sure you changed the 4th argument in the constructor to `true`.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking Kirk Backus but i'm realizing that the problem could be with the PHP script which sets the $hmtl var.